# Unexpected SQLite3 Statement::clear behavior

Tags: php, sqlite, prepare

Binding less values for a new row using prepared statement than the previous row, actually writes data from previous row.

Look at this example:

```
$db = new SQLite3('test.sqlite');
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (column1, column2, column3);');

$stmt  = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO test (column1, column2, column3) values (:0, :1, :2)');

$data = array(
  array('a', 'b', 'c'),
  array('a', 'b', 'c'),
  array('x')
);

foreach($data as $row)
{
  foreach($row as $index => $column)
  {
    $stmt->bindValue(':'.$index, $column, SQLITE3_TEXT);
  }
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->clear();
}
```

Expected behavior is following table:

```
a|b|c
a|b|c
x||
```

Actually the result is

```
a|b|c
a|b|c
x|b|c
```

I'd like to understand it if the behavior is on purpose. ::clear doesn't seem to clear bound values at all.

Comment: You must call [reset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.reset.php) after `execute`, but that shouldn't make any difference for the parameters …

Comment: Even with $stmt->reset() it's the same result.